# regex specific char from end of a word

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace every word ending with "h", but if the character before "h" was one of these `(l|m|t|s)`, then no need to replace.
this is what I'm doing in java:

```
String t1="samplh sampleh samplah sampmh";
System.out.print(t1.replaceAll("(l|m|t|s)h","#"));
```

but it gives me this (replaces both grouped char and "h"):

```
samp# sampleh samplah samp#
```

it should look like this (just "h" must be replaced by "#"):

```
sampl# sampleh samplah sampm#
```

Comment: I ran out of breath . Reading this String t1="samplh sampleh samplah sampmh";

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic, do you mean only when h has a vowel before it must replaced by #? Because in your example all words end by h.

Comment: You say that if 'h' is preceded by 'l' then the 'h' shouldn't be replaced and then you say that samplh should become sampl#. That is contradictory.

Comment: What do you mean here " but if the character before "h" was one of these (l|m|t|s),hen no need to replace."

Comment: no, that's just a sample sentence. if any of (l|m|t|s) comes before "h" word which "h" is in the end of a word, the "h" must be replaced with "#", not "lh" with "#".

Comment: You're right, @mikea. But what's contradictory?

Comment: Ok, maybe not contradictory just badly worded

Comment: You need to put () around the h and then replace group 2..

group 0 is the entire match (lh/mh), group 1 is the single character (which you can replace with [lmts]

and group 1 is the h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(?<=[lmts])h(?=\s|$)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/iR4zV0

java:

```
String t1="samplh sampleh samplah sampmh";
System.out.print(t1.replaceAll("(?<=[lmts])h(?=\s|$)","#"));
```

Output:

```
sampl# sampleh samplah sampm#
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
Find what:    \b(\w+)([^lmts])(h)\b
Replace with: $1$2#
```

Java:

```
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

/**
   <P>{@code java ReplaceHAtEnd}</P>
 **/
public class ReplaceHAtEnd  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

      String sRegex = "" +
         "\\b" +            //word start
            "(\\w+)" +      //one or more characters
            "([^lmts])" +   //character other than l,m,t,s
            "(h)" +         //the letter 'h'
         "\\b";             //word end

      String sToSearch = "samplh sampleh samplah sampmh";
      String sRplcWith = "$1$2#";
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sRegex).matcher(sToSearch);

      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while(m.find())  {
         m.appendReplacement(sb, sRplcWith);
         m.appendTail(sb);
      }

      System.out.println(sb);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ReplaceHAtEnd
samplh sample# samplah sampmh sampla# sampmh
```

Try it at regexplanet: http://fiddle.re/hnqvf

or [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3bwA2UbCMi3oD56D)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Actually, you migt want to change `\w+` to `\w*`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
t1.replaceAll("(?<=[lmts])h\\b", "#");
```

Answer (score 0):

To statisfy your condition - use following regex :
[^(l|m|t|s)]h\b

\b : [word boundry](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
[^(l|m|t|s)] : The penultimate word must not be l or m or t or s

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
            final String t1 = "slhplh sampleh samplah sampmh";
            System.out.print(t1.replaceAll("[^(l|m|t|s)]h\\b", "#"));
    }
}
```